# Pan and zoom in pyplot are very slow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making visualizations for a machine learning project that I'm working on and I'm using matplotlib for the plots. The backend for matplotlib is Qt4Agg. The amount of points plotted is less than 100.

The pan and zoom are veery slow. Do you know what could the reason for this?

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from classifier import Classifier

cl = Classifier(1)
with open("./data/enolase-01.bounds") as file:
    data = file.read().strip().split("\n")
    xdim = int(data[7].split(" ")[-1])
    ydim = int(data[8].split(" ")[-1])
    zdim = int(data[9].split(" ")[-1])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")

for i, n in enumerate(cl.X[0]):
    z = i % zdim
    y = i / zdim % ydim
    x = i / zdim / ydim % xdim
    if n == 0.0:
        continue
    ax.scatter([x], [y], [z], c='r', marker="o")
    #print x, y, z


ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Comment: There isn't anything in your code that would explain what you're experiencing. However, consider reducing your example to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and check the functionality again. Chances are the slowdown is related to other pieces of code. Also, `enumerate` returns a tuple, the first element of which is an integer (the index), the 2nd an element of an iterator. Your (shown) code can be reduced by removing the `import classifier...` and only calling `ax.scatter` once by making use of numpy's `ndarray`s.
First *reduce your code* though, to find out where the problem is.

Comment: I figured out that the problem is that I'm calling scatter way too many times. I'm calling it once for each of 700+ points and each is a scatter plot. Putting everything into a single call removed all lag in pan and zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is that I'm calling scatter way too many times. I'm calling it once for each of 700+ points and each is a scatter plot. Putting everything into a single call removed all lag in pan and zoom.